# blpop is blocking for much longer than the timeout in a Rails process after moving to VPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, vpc

I have a timeout of 3 seconds and expect blpop to only hang for 3 seconds at the most, but I am experiencing my Rails process hang randomly for longer than that, sometimes up to 500 seconds.

The code that hangs is:

```
  ...
  if timeout # equals 3 
    # blocking mode
    queue.redis.blpop(*slot_keys, timeout)
  else
  ...
```

I am using the redis gem, version 3.0.4. Any suggestions on how I can debug this?

As a side note this issue starting coming up after we moved our processes to Amazon's VPC.

Answer (score 1):

While not documented, the reason you're waiting more than needed is cause you're not passing the blocking timeout properly.

Proper method call:

`queue.redis.blpop(*slot_keys, timeout: timeout)`

(src: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/29653bbc1e9d8ab6090107eacb2fde4d4a6af1aa/lib/redis.rb#L1144)